# What is the correct way to call API inside a Modal, when it's visible in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Suppose that I have a Modal inside a Component and I want to show the Modal when some buttons are clicked:

```
render(){
  ...
  <Modal 
   is={this.state.productId} 
   visilble={this.state.visible} 
  />
}
```

Inside the Modal Component, I want to call API to get the product detail based on the selected id as the following:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.visible && !this.props.visible) {
      fetch(...).then(res => {
        this.setState({
          product: res.data
        })
      }).catch(err => {
        ...
      })
    }
  }
```

From the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html) it says that componentWillReceiveProps, componentWillUpdate is deprecated and you should avoid them in new code.So I try use static getDerivedStateFromProps()

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps()(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.visible && ...) {
    fetch(...).then(res => {
      return {
       product: res.data
      }
    }).catch(err => {
      ...
    })
   } else return null (or just return null here without else)
}
```

The above code doesn't work since fetch is asynchronous so it always returns null or doesn't return anything, you can't use await here to wait for the api to resolve also, and I heard that getDerivedStateFromProps shouldn't use for data fetching.

So what is the best way solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to decide whether to show Modal component or not in parent component as Modal component should be a functional component to render only modal related view. This way every time Modal component will not be rendered and only rendered when visible flag is true.

```
{ this.state.visible &&
  <Modal />
}
```

In parent component you could fetch data in componentDidMount if just after initial render the data is required or componentDidUpdate if after every update the fetch data is required for modal. After fetching data set state of visible to true.

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: I updated the question,the Modal need to call API based on productId passed from parent Component

Comment: Just create a wrapper component for Modal say ModalContainer, call api from ModalContainer and when data is fetched(visible: true) then render Modal component. Separation of concerns.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount the `Modal` based on `this.state.visible` and start fetching when `Modal` is mounted on [componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) or when the props are changing through [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)

```
// delay
const delay = () => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000));

// fake products
const products = [
  { id: 1, text: "product 1" },
  { id: 2, text: "product 2" },
  { id: 3, text: "product 3" }
];

// fake ajax call
const API = async productId => {
  await delay();
  return products.find(p => p.id === productId);
};

class Parent extends Component {
  state = { productId: 1, visible: false };

  toggleShow = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({ visible: !prevState.visible }));
  };

  setProductId = productId => this.setState({ productId, visible: true });

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.toggleShow}>show or hide</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setProductId(1)}>fetch product 1</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setProductId(2)}>fetch product 2</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setProductId(3)}>fetch product 3</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.setProductId(4)}>unknown product id</button>
        {this.state.visible && <Modal is={this.state.productId} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Modal extends Component {
  state = { product: null, fetching: false };

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.fetchProduct();
  };

  componentDidUpdate = prevProps => {
    if (prevProps.is !== this.props.is) {
      this.fetchProduct();
    }
  };

  fetchProduct = async () => {
    this.setState({ fetching: true });
    const product = await API(this.props.is);
    this.setState({ product, fetching: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { product, fetching } = this.state;

    if (fetching) return <h1>{`fetching product ${this.props.is}`}</h1>;

    return product ? (
      <div>
        <h1>{`product id: ${product.id}`}</h1>
        <h3>{`text: ${product.text}`}</h3>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <h1>Product not found</h1>
    );
  }
}
```

[SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/93w8785qqp)

Answer (score 0):

Actually in another approach, you can use `<modal/>` in another **pureComponent**
(for example: `componentContainer`) and just call it in your main view. and use just one object inside your main view state as your `<componentContainer/>` data scope and give it as a property like this code

```
  construcor(prop){
        super(props);
         this.state={
          productDetail:null<<change this in data fetch
          }
   }
<componentContainer data={this.state.productDetail} modalVisible={this.state.changeNumderModal}/>
```

and inside your component container:

```
     <Modal
            animationType="fade"
            transparent={true}
            visible={this.props.modalVisible}//<<<<<<<<<
            onRequestClose={() => {

            }}>
                    //contents:
                     this.props.data.map(()=>//-----)
            </View>
        </Modal>
```

in this method you have just one modal and one scope as its data, you can call the **fetch**s and other functions in your main component as others... and if its so needed you can even pass a function as property to modal container to :

```
   someFunction(someval){
      //do some thing  
      }

    <componentContainer data={this.state.productDetail} modalVisible={this.state.changeNumderModal} someFunction={(val)=>this.someFunction(val)}/>
```

and call it inside  :

```
          this.props.someFunction('what ever you want')
```

Answer (score 0):

So Let's assume you did that hide and show of modal with button click, now whenever the model will open
inside the componentWillMount function

```
class Modal extends Component {

  this.state = {product:[], loader : false}

  componentWillMount(){
    fetch(...).then(res => {
     this.setState({
       product: res.data
     })
    }).catch(err => {
      ...
    })
  }

  render(){
    const {product, loader} = this.state;
    return (
      if (loader) return <ProductComponent data = {product}/> 
      else return <div> No data found </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach below:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    if (this.props.visible && !prevProps.visible) {
        // make the API call here
    }
}
```